# Xamarin Forms Absolute Layout instead of Relative Layout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Since Jason Smith didn't recommend Relative layout and said that we should use Absolute layout I have a question how can we deal with RelativeToView concept?

Absolute Layout sets proportional coordinates and sizes of the elements within itself relative to itself not to each other as RelativeLayout. What to do if I need some elements to be relative to each other? Creating additional Grids and StackLayouts? I would rather use RelativeLayout then or I am missing something.

Decided to add a simplest example and consider we are talking ONLY about Relative and Absolute layouts, no Stack, no Grid. I have 2 buttons and I want to place them as shown in the picture

[image]
With absolute layout I could define the position of the top button and say it's height 10% of the screen. Now I could shift the bottom button by saying it starts at 11% of the screen. BUT this will change my top button height. If I want my top button to be it's natural "auto" size I cannot do that. So, how can I put my bottom button under top one if I have no idea how much top button occupies on screen? I know how to do it with Relative but how I can do it with Absolute Layout?

It looks like the solution is nest bunch of layouts https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout/
Is that the only way? Is that performance still better than Relative layout?

Answer (score 1):

By its nature [RelativeLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout/) is powerful and offers layouting options that no other Layout on its own does. But that power comes at a cost in performance. Resolving the constraint dependencies consistently and obtaining a final layout doesn't come cheaply.

The point is not necessarily that `RelativeLayout` should never be used, rather that often times other Layouts can do the job, and yes, even 2-3 nested Layouts can be more performant than a single equivalent RelativePanel.

[Grid](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/) in particular is a powerful option with which similar effects can be achieved by astute use of Auto, Star, and/or absolute-sized rows and columns as appropriate, plus RowSpan and ColumnSpan, plus element margins, etc.

To consider your specific example, I don't know of a way to achieve what you want with an `AbsoluteLayout`, at least without the added complication of attached properties. But it seems like a natural fit for a `Grid` with `RowSpan="Auto"` on the first row. From a diagram alone I can't tell exactly what other constraints you're going for.

Comment: ok, lets assume the first row is auto. what do do with the second row where bottom button starts from the middle of top button? how do I construct column spans?

Comment: I had a quick go and couldn't find a way to do this (bottom button left-aligned with centre of top button) with column spans. But for that matter I can't see a way to do this with multiple nested layouts. Can you? It seems very RelativeLayout-specific.

Comment: In theory it is possible to calculate half width of the button and from that calculate percentage of the width of the screen but is it worth it? And probably has to be done in code not xml

Comment: see above, Forgot to add you in previous comment

Comment: 'Worth it' depends on the use case. If it's just a couple of buttons, use the RelativeLayout, it's no big deal. If you've got a lot of subviews, *and* it's in a performance-critical part of the UI (eg the template of a ListView), *and* testing has identified a real performance issue, then you may want to consider code-behind in place of the RelativeLayout.